# How to use IndexedDB with Selenium in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, selenium, indexeddb

Maybe this issue has a solution, but I haven't found it yet. I want to use Selenium and IndexedDB together, but I just can't. IndexedDB requires a browser-context, and need to be lauched from an HTML form as far as I know, and Selenium launches its own browser depending of web-driver, and I can't get them to work together, I mean, launch Chrome or Firefox from Selenium, go to a web page, extract some data and the store that data using IndexedDB. Using separate js files works but when I put them together, always get the same error `ReferenceError: window is not defined`.
Also, I know that Selenium works in several languajes like Python, but indexedDB doesn't, and Seletools seems very simple and without all options that JS version has.
How can I do this?

This is my SeleniumFile.js:

```
const {Builder, By, Key, until} = require("selenium-webdriver");
(async function example(){
    let driver = await new Builder().forBrowser('firefox').build();
    try {
        await driver.get('http://www.google.com/ncr');
        await driver.findElement(By.name('q')).sendKeys('webdriver', Key.RETURN);
        await driver.wait(until.titleContains('webdriver'), 1000);
    } finally {
        await driver.quit();
    }
};)();
```

And this is my IndexedDBEx.js file:

```
const indexedDB = window.indexedDB;
const request = indexedDB.open("SeleniumDB", 1);
request.onerror = function (event) {
    console.error("Error with indexedDB");
    console.error(event);
};

request.onupgradeneeded = function () {
    const db = request.result;
    const store = db.createObjectStore("Pages", {keyPath: "id", autoIncrement: true});
};

request.onsuccess = function () {
    const db = request.result;
    const transaction = db.transaction("Pages", "readwrite");

    const store = transaction.objectStore("Pages");
    store.createIndex("text", ["text"], {unique: false});
    store.put({text: "Sample text"});

    transaction.oncomplete = function () {
        db.close();
    };
};
```